# Audited tables using Hibernate-Envers

Tags: java, hibernate, firebird

I have a problem with Envers configuration. I can't do it create an audited table on my firebird database. For testing, I created a table "Envers" manually in database, then I can that Envers create a "Envers_AUD" for me, but without success.

Thanks!

**persistence.xml**

`<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect" />
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />`

**Envers.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity; 
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;

@Entity(name="ENVERS")
@Audited
@SequenceGenerator(name = "GEN_ENVERS_ID", sequenceName = "GEN_ENVERS_ID", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
public class Envers implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "GEN_ENVERS_ID")
    private Integer id;            
    private Double camponum;
    private String nome;
    private String chave;
    private Double valor; 
    private Integer status;

... getters and setters...
```

**Error on JBOSS AS 7.1 final**

```
15:25:29,640 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http-esrjo3a8594i55.mesop.intrabb.bb.com.br-172.22.32.152-443-1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component EnversDAO for method public void br.com.bb.dtvm.enver.EnversDAO.adiciona(br.com.bb.dtvm.enver.Envers): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:115) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:95) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]

...

Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1177)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:117)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:92) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 58 more
**Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -204
Table unknown
ENVERS_LOG
At line 1, column 13
    at** org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler.continueInvocation(ConnectionProxyHandler.java:146) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.buildBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:144) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.getBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:127) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2827) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3290) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:80) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:272) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:264) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:186) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1081) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcess.java:157) [hibernate-envers-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:566) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:218) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:510) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:113) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:273)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:93)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:164)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165)
    ... 61 more
```

Comment: The problem is in missing table ENVERS_LOG

Comment: Did you define `AuditEventListener`?

Comment: No, my Envers version is 4.2.0.Final, this version contains embebedd the AuditEventListener yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. The fix was to remove old table and allow Hibernate/JPA create tables on his own - otherwise I was receiving same error as you have right now.